# Simple jQuery question

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a tutorial.  I did one tutorial and things were great. Moving onto another and I can't get it to work.  I'm only posting because I just started this tutorial and things aren't working.  When 'Hello World' doesn't work I get frustrated.  Anyway, here is my HTML. Nothing special here.  I'm expecting a Hello World alert on page load, but I get nothing.

```
<html>                                                                  
<head>                                                                  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
    <script type="text/javascript">  

        $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Hello World");
    });

    </script>  

</head>                                                                 
<body>                                                                  
    <h2>My jQuery Test page</h2>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<br>                                      
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
</body>
```

The original code was more complex, but it won't work either.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a").click(function() {
     alert("Hello world!");
   });
 });
```

Comment: check the path of your jquery file you specified in the src attribute.

Comment: As people said below - your jquery.js isn't in the same directory. The code is valid.

Comment: I'm guessing jQuery just isn't being loaded. If this is the case, you should see something like `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in your console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue might be the reference for the jquery.js, as the code that you have appears correct. (You can find more information regarding both directly including jQuery or using a CDN [here.](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery))

You may want to check that your code is in the proper directory, or if you are having difficulty you can use one of the CDN hosted versions by including:

```
<script src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js”>
</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cTK8v/)

Comment: The file existed but the file was empty. After using Rionmonster's link and getting it to work, I found the issue.

Comment: Glad you were able to find a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Only thing i could think of is that the jquery.js doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your are getting a javascript error.  Possibly your jquery path is incorrect.
You could try including your jquery  from google:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.js"></script>
```